# Refreshing the task bar after installation

Tags: inno-setup

In my latest version of my application I changed the icon.

I noticed that when I completed running the updated installer that the existing icon still displayed on the Windows 11 taskbar. I rebooted and it was fine.

Is there no way to get the taskbar to update without the need to reboot?

---

To clarify, I already have this setting in the `[Setup]` section:

`ChangesAssociations=yes`